# How to properly read data from SqlDataReader in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

Let us assume we have an open `SqlConnection` and execute an arbitrary query resulting in a table consisting of one column *Foo* which contains integers.

To read those integers I noticed two kinds of possibilities to access the values in the column:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // access value directly either by column name or index
            int i = (int)reader["Foo"];
            int j = (int)reader[0];

            // access value by using GetOrdinal
            int k = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Foo"));
        }
    }
}
```

Both approaches result in the same values of course. I am using the first approach as it seems easier to me to use the column name to access the value directly instead of using it to get its index and then using that index to access the value.

But I am quite new to the subject so what are the best practices here? Current conventions? Differences in matters of performance?

Comment: Well, performance wise: the `reader.GetOrdinal("Foo")` should be stored in a variable outside the loop. As for the indexer vs the method call; i am blank there :-)

Comment: `if (reader.HasRows)` is completely *redundant*, just remove it

Comment: Note that your `if (reader.HasRows)` is useless in your case. The `while` would just return false on the first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using reflector you can see the indexer `[]` internally is the same as calling the methods

```
public override object this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetValue(i);
    }
}
public override object this[string name]
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetValue(this.GetOrdinal(name));
    }
}
```

so the actual difference is. if you know the position and care about performance use the int version of the methods.

```
 int j = (int)reader[0];//direct array access for some column
 int j = reader.GetInt32(0);
```

if you don't know the position or prefer readability use the string version

```
 //must first goto hash table and waist time looking for column index
 int j = (int)reader["price"]; //but at least we know the meaning of the column
 int j = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("price"));
 int j = (int)reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("price"));
```

and to finalize the difference bettween  `GetInt32` and `GetValue` is just that `GetInt32` does the type validation and cast for you, so if you know the type of data makes you life easier..

PS. the performance hit of looking up the index of the column by name is usually ignorable.. but.. is not to be dismissed, I have a project where `GetOrdinal` that is one of the most called functions hundreds of thousand of times, summing up to seconds of time, that I could have avoided by using ints, and now that I'm hitting bottlenecks, I can't rewrite the application.

Comment: You can call GetOrdinal once for each column and save indices in variables. You can make the calls just after ExecuteReader and before beginning the loop.

Answer (score 3):

All are correct way but `reader["Foo"]` and `reader[0]` are using the overloaded indexers defined. It's always easy/readable and recommended to use the column name in the indexer instead of using the index though. Not sure about any performance differences between them.

```
        int i = (int)reader["Foo"];
        int j = (int)reader[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
  // if (reader.HasRows) is redundant

  // do not repeat this in the loop
  int k_index = reader.GetOrdinal("Foo");

  while (reader.Read()) { 
    // reader["Foo"] is not necessary int; 
    // better practice is to convert since reader["Foo"] could be, say, Oracle Number
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Foo"]);
    // usually, reader[123] (instead of reader["MyField"]) syntax looks ugly, but
    // it may happen that, say, "id" is always the first field in the query - 
    // so reader[0] syntax is reasonable  
    int j = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
    // what if reader[index] is declared as Int64 but contains Int32 values - convert
    int k = Convert.ToInt32(reader[k_index]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use `SqlDataReader` a lot so keep it more simple as possible, specifying column name:

```
int i = (int)reader["Foo"];
```